# Can i stop vim creating the .swp swap files?

Tags: vim

They are cluttering up my working dir. Maybe it could just put them in the vim directory or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable it with

`set noswap`

in your _vimrc. As a matter of fact, that is the prefered behaviour when working with *really large* files. See more under ***:help swapfile***

For settings them aside in a predefined directory, tis would be best to [read a bit of this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_swap_and_backup_files_from_your_working_directory)

Answer (score 7):

You can change the directory for swap files in .vimrc with

> set directory=/tmp

See [directory](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27directory%27) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned,

```
set noswap # in vimrc

:bufdo set noswap # when running
```

Or upon launch:

```
vim -n
```

Answer (score 4):

Using:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012 04:25:35)
...
```

**:help swapfile** shows the command as: `noswapfile`